# React - display post details

Tags: reactjs

I have created page to display post details. I can see all the correct data in console but nothing is rendering on the page. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function ProductDetail({ match }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchItem();
        console.log(match);
    }, []);

    const [item, setItem] = useState({});

    const fetchItem = async () => {
        const data = await fetch(`http://amb.local/posts/${match.params.id}`);
        const item = await data.json();
        console.log(item);
        setItem(item);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Post detail</h2>
            <h3> 
              {item.title}
            </h3>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductDetail;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to get [exhaustive deps](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) working for your dev environment because now your effect has missing dependencies that you obviously don't know about. Fixing the dependency would cause ProductDetail to re render every time.

Here is an example of how you could do it:

```js
function ProductDetail({ match }) {
  const [item, setItem] = React.useState({});
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${match}`
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(todo => setItem(todo));
  }, [match]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Post detail for {item.id}</h2>
      <h3>{item.title}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
const ProductSelector = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      <select
        value={selected}
        onChange={e => setSelected(e.target.value)}
      >
        {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map(id => (
          <option key={id} value={id}>
            {id}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <ProductDetail match={selected} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <ProductSelector />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```